# ACF with Timber isn't displaying on the front page

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, timber

I'm working with Timber and Advanced Custom Fields on new Wordpress project. I created some new widgets and uses some ACF. Everything worked fine. Now I'mb building front page and using twig files. I have strange problem because I've created many fields like repeater, text, some textarea etc. and everything's working in WP but I can't display it on the page. There are empty values inside tags. I don't know what am I doing wrong.

front-page.twig

```
<div class="col-md-half">
    <h2>{{ post.why_header }}</h2>
    <p>{{ post.why_text }}</p>
  </div>
```

front-page.php

```
<?php

/**
 * @package  WordPress
 * @subpackage  Timber
 * @since    Timber 0.1
 */


$context = Timber::get_context();
$post = new Timber\Post();
$context['post'] = $post;
Timber::render(array('front-page.twig'), $context);
```

Of course my ACF names are like: `why_header` and `why_text`and inside ACF inputs there is some text.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.. front-page wasn't set as a front page..